# WCF Custom Authentication

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have a requirement to expose my wcf services to other vendors. For internal client's the authentication is pretty straight forward i.e. to use Windows Authentication with AzMan role provider.

My next step is to expose the same services to external customers. Since they are not on our Network, I'm wondering how I could implement the Role Based Authentication so that I can grant/deny the request to particular Operation.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest configure AzMan to use ADAM (Active Directory Application Mode).  This way you can have own database (AD) of external users with your defined roles, and AzMan will call that ADAM to check user roles.  I've done it and it works fine.  Here is the link for how to implement it: [How To: Use ADAM for Roles in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647400.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a software communicating with your service - Certificate authentication.

If it's a human - Username/Password

Comment: Thanks @Maxmim, not sure how do I achive both of your solutions. I'm quiet new to WCF. WOuld you be able to help me

Comment: @flybyte - Sure, which one of them do you need?